# Linking to files in different directory in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error, require

My other question about getting help with the programming side of **wordpress** was labeled off topic for some reason so I'm asking **a different way**. I'm trying to embed my wordpress posts. I'm using this tutorial:

> http://www.corvidworks.com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages

The problem is with this code:

```
<?php

// Include WordPress 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wordpress/wp-load.php');
query_posts('showposts=1');

?>`
```

When I try to run the page that this is inserted into, I get the error saying that file doesn't exist. Pretending my domain is blah.com, the file is in www.blah.com/wordpress/wp-load.php and the page that includes this PHP code is in www.blah.com/other/page.php.

How do I change the syntax of the link on the require line to make sure it's pointing to the right place since right now it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: unless you're using full-blown urls in your require/include statements, those paths are relative to the file system of your server, not the url-space. You need to consider where the two scripts are on the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks! So I'm asking HOW to write the full links? The wp-load.php file is in the "wordpress" directory. The file this php code is in is in the "other" directory. Both directories are subdirectories of the root. How do I write the full link to the wp-load.php file?

Comment: Lower in the tutorial where it talks about using the full path is shows: require('/var/www/example.com/wordpress/wp-load.php') so i tried that (obviously using my domain instead of example.com) and it still said the file didn't exist. i'm having a hard time just finding a page that explains link syntax. i don't know what the var means or why there has to be a slash after www instead of the dot so I need help figuring out how to properly write the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried with

```
require('../wordpress/wp-load.php');
```

or anyway something like

```
require('../../wordpress/wp-load.php');
```

?

(depending on the depth of your file position)

Comment: Thanks so much! Using the dot dot slash worked!!! I read about that when I looked up syntax but the way it was described, I thought it would go one back from my root directory and end up looking one directory too far behind. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just like the above answer

This worked for me

```
require('../wordpress/wp-load.php');
```